# Spring 3 binding object to list

Tags: spring

I think my syntax is correct, but the list in my form backing object is not getting populated. It looks like the list itself is being made, just that it has no elements. The other attributes are being populated as expected. Any ideas?

JSP:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="addReminder">
    Reminder Name <input type='text' name='reminderName' placeholder="Reminder Name"> <br />
    Date          <input type='text' name='date' placeholder="1/05/2013"> <br />
    Time          <input type='text' name='time' placeholder="4:00 PM"> <br />
    Time Zone     <input type='text' name='timeZone' placeholder="EDT"> <br />
    <br />
    Contacts    <input type='text' path="contacts[0].phoneNumber" placeholder="Name"> <br />
                <input type='text' path="contacts[1].phoneNumber" placeholder="Name"> <br />

                <input type="submit" value = "Add Reminder">
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/AddAReminder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addReminder(@ModelAttribute("addReminder") AddReminder reminder, BindingResult result)
{
            //does stuff with the data from the form backing object

    return "Add A Reminder";
}
```

Form backing object:

```
public class AddReminder
{
private String reminderName;
private String date;
private String time;
private String timeZone;
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
private String sentFrom;
private String message;
private String provider;

//getters and setters
```

Contact object:

```
public class Contact
{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phoneNumber;
private String provider;

//getters and setters
```

Comment: Ok I figured out what change I made that got this working. I initialize the list with a Contact object on the GET request. I say initalize, but I mean I just add an element to the list so it isn't empty. The list itself is already initialized in the AddReminder class. Spring will then auto grow the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<c:forEach>`  as :

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="allProductEdit">
   <c:forEach items="${allProductEdit.products}" var="prod" varStatus="pStatus">
      <form:input path="products[${pStatus.index}].description" />
      <form:input path="products[${pStatus.index}].price" />
   </c:forEach>
   <input type="submit" value="Execute">
</form:form>
```

check this forum link http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?54509-lt-form-input-gt-inside-lt-c-forEach-gt

Comment: Ah sorry I failed to mention, the list is empty, which is why I didn't use a foreach. I'm trying to populate the empty list from the information off of the form, but am having trouble doing that.

Comment: umm ok weird. restarted eclipse and now my list is populating. well, thanks for the link anyway, good to know more about spring.

Comment: I do not think that you have problem if list is empty but in case you faced this problem use c:if to check size of llistt first if 0 do not execute c:foreach

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out what change I made that got this working. I initialize the list with a Contact object on the GET request. I say initalize, but I mean I just add an element to the list so it isn't empty. The list itself is already initialized in the AddReminder class. Spring will then auto grow the list.